# Code syntax error, "userfullName undefined"

Tags: google, query-variable

I'm working on a WordPress site that is using Google Visualization API Query Language to get a chart onto a page, using the data of the current logged in user. I'm using the function wp_get_current_user() to get the user data and

```
$current_user = wp_get_current_user();
```

I've been working on this for days, this is the closest I've been able to get, but I'm getting a "userfullName undefined" on my $current_user variable.

My code:

```
<?php
   if (is_page( 'home' )) { ?>

 // This piece is supposed to be in the code below, but it throws an error on the return;
 //<?php
//$current_user = wp_get_current_user();
//if ( !($current_user) ) { 
//                return;
//}
 //?>

   <?php
      $current_user = wp_get_current_user();
   ?>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  google.load('visualization', '1', {packages: ['linechart']});
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">

userfullName = <?php $current_user->display_name;?>
Querystring = 'select C, max(G) where A = "' + userfullName + '" group by C order by C asc';

var visualization;

    function drawVisualization() {
  var query = new google.visualization.Query(
      'http://spreadsheets.google.com/tq?key=KEY_GOES_HERE&gid=0&pub=0');

  // Apply query language.
  query.setQuery(Querystring);

  // Send the query with a callback function.
  query.send(handleQueryResponse);
}

function handleQueryResponse(response) {
  if (response.isError()) {
    alert('Error in query: ' + response.getMessage() + ' ' + response.getDetailedMessage());
    return;
  }

  var data = response.getDataTable();
  visualization = new google.visualization. LineChart(document.getElementById('visualization'));
  visualization.draw(data, {legend: 'top'});
}

google.setOnLoadCallback(drawVisualization);
</script>
<?php } 
?>
```

Any help figuring out why this is coming up "undefined" would be appreciated. I'm a novice with the coding, so if this is the wrong approach entirely, please advise. We're trying to draw the chart based on who is currently logged into the portal. The code is supposed to grab their data and display it.

Thanks!

Comment: `userfullName = <?php $current_user->display_name;?> ` should be `userfullName = <?php echo $current_user->display_name; ?>`

Comment: You should better use a separate `.js`/JavaScript file and register/enqueue/localize it properly. Would help you (a) with debugging, (b) you would gain everything that browser cache provides (c) you could make use a concatenation, minification and (d) Caching plugins would help you as well.

Comment: Please read again what @G.M. told you. This is the source of your problem.

Comment: Thanks, Kaiser. I got the script working, but have discovered other issues with this method, other than the ones you mentioned. We will have to find a better way to do this without using Google Spreadsheets, which requires a public link for the spreadsheet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing the 'echo'

```
userfullName = <?php $current_user->display_name;?>
```

should be

```
var userfullName = "<?php echo $current_user->display_name;?>"
```

AND notice that I put quotes around that too.

BUT!!!!

You should really look at using [wp_localize_script](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_localize_script) for declaring javascript variables.

Example:

```
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'fobu_front_scripts');

function fobu_front_scripts() {

    global $blog_id;
    $params = array( 
        'site_url' => site_url(),
        'blog_id' => $blog_id
    );

    wp_localize_script( 'jquery', 'MyScriptParams', $params );
}
```

Comment: Thank you, Douglas! I will try that out and check out that script.

Comment: Yes, that works perfectly! Now to figure out how to localize the script.

Comment: I added quick example for the wp_localize_script (I did not test).  Hopefully, that will give you a starting point.  Now you can access variable like MyScriptParams.blog_id in Javascript.